# Text on Tkinter app when microphone is active

Tags: python, tkinter, speech-recognition, speech

I am working on virtual assistant project where i want my once my mircophone is activated to speak it shows on tkinter app that user can "Speak now...". this is the part of my code where i am facing an issue text correctly gets printed on python console at right time when microphone gets activated but it comes on tkniter app when whole loop of code gets finished.

Please help me here.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import speech_recognition as sr 
import playsound # to play saved mp3 file 
from gtts import gTTS # google text to speech 
import os # to save/open files 

import winsound

def get_audio(): 
    rObject = sr.Recognizer() 
    #audio = '' 
    
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        t1="Speak Now..."
        print(t1)
        winsound.Beep(1000,500)
        root.configure(background='green')
        Label(root,text=t1,font=('Arial',10)).pack(side='left')
        #rObject.pause_threshold = 1
        #audio = rObject.listen(source)
        #rObject.pause_threshold = 1
        # recording the audio using speech recognition 
        
        audio = rObject.listen(source) 
        print("Stop.") # limit 5 secs 
        
    try: 
        text = rObject.recognize_google(audio, language ='en-in') 
        print("You : ", text) 
        return text 

except Exception as e:
    print(e) 
    print("Unable to Recognize your voice.") 
    return "None"

return query
```

Comment: indentations are correct in this code and what is the last statement is returning??

Comment: yes indentations are correct in this code last statement will return query that will have user speech in text. My Motive is that code understands and also writes same text on the tkinter app.

Comment: No! Indentation are not correct. You had this outside except Exception as e:
    print(e) 
    print("Unable to Recognize your voice.") 
    return "None" of while block condition.